# excel vba code corrupting my file consistently after a few runs

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, corruption

I have a relatively long set of subs that get run on a list of my excel files a few times a day. after a few runs, the file then becomes corrupted which normally would not be an issue b/c it doesn't really effect any of the data. however, I have another program that opens up each of the excel and pulls some key data from each one to make a summary sheet. because the corrupted file gives a message that says something along the lines of "there is a problem with some of your content" the summary program stops with a

> run-time error '1004': Method of object 'Workbooks' Failed

I can not for the life of me figure out what in my code is causing the corruption. Is there a way I can have the summary code ignore the corruption notification? Ive tried a handful of different things including turning the application notifications off in my code to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated! ill post my all my code with a brief description below:

> Here is the code from the summary file that opens each of the
>   individual files and pulls data:

```
Sub OEEsummmary()
Dim ActCycCell, ExpCycCell, ExpCurCycCell, ShiftCell, DifCell, DownCell, DTResACell, DTResBCell, PartCell, OpNamCell, OprCell, RejCell, RejResCell As Range
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim Txt$, MyPath$, MyWB$
Dim myValue As Integer
Dim x As Long
Dim v As Variant, r As Range, rWhere As Range
MyPath = "L:\Manufacturing Engineering\Samuel Hatcher\"
x = 2
Set MySheet = ActiveSheet

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

MySheet.Range("B2:G18").ClearContents
MySheet.Range("J2:O18").ClearContents

Do While MySheet.Range("A" & x).Value <> ""
    MyWB = MySheet.Range("A" & x).Text
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyWB, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True

    Set ActCycCell = ActiveSheet.Range("E21")
    Set ExpCycCell = ActiveSheet.Range("D21")
    Set ShiftCell = ActiveSheet.Range("E2")
    Set DownCell = ActiveSheet.Range("K28")
    Set DTResACell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Downtime").Range("O9")
    Set DTResBCell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Downtime").Range("O10")
    Set PartCell = ActiveSheet.Range("E4")
    Set ExpCurCycCell = ActiveSheet.Range("D22")
    If ActiveSheet.Range("I3") = "" Then
        Set OpNamCell = ActiveSheet.Range("I2")
        Else
        Set OpNamCell = ActiveSheet.Range("I3")
    End If
    Set OprCell = ActiveSheet.Range("C4")
    Set RejCell = ActiveSheet.Range("H21")
    Set RejResCell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rejected Parts").Range("H5")
        With MySheet.Range("A" & x)
            .Offset(0, 14).Value = OprCell.Value
            .Offset(0, 13).Value = OpNamCell.Value
            .Offset(0, 12).Value = PartCell.Value
            .Offset(0, 11).Value = ShiftCell.Value
            .Offset(0, 10).Value = RejResCell.Value
            .Offset(0, 9).Value = RejCell.Value
            .Offset(0, 6).Value = ActCycCell.Value
            .Offset(0, 5).Value = ExpCycCell.Value
            .Offset(0, 4).Value = ExpCurCycCell.Value
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = DTResBCell.Value
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = DTResACell.Value
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = DownCell.Value
        End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    x = x + 1
Loop

Call sort
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

> Clears the page of data to prepare it for a new shift of entering
>   data:

```
Sub ClearFrontEnd()


Sheets("Front End").Unprotect ("29745")
'prompts user to confirm if they realy want to clear entry
response = MsgBox("Are You Sure?", vbYesNo)

If response = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'checks to see if operator number is there
If range("I3").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "ENTER OPORATOR # AND CLICK NEW SHIFT AGAIN"

Else

    Call StopTimer
    Call prodChoose
    Call transfer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

Sheets("Front End").Unprotect ("29745")
    Sheets("Front End").Select
'Deletes the data from the entry and unique key fields
    range("E8:E20").ClearContents
    range("I8:I27").ClearContents
    range("J8:J27").ClearContents
    range("K8:K27").ClearContents
    range("I3").ClearContents
    range("H8").Value = ""
    range("H9").Value = ""
    range("H10").Value = ""
    range("H11").Value = ""
    range("H12").Value = ""
    range("H13").Value = ""
    range("H14").Value = ""
    range("H15").Value = ""
    range("H16").Value = ""
    range("H17").Value = ""
    range("H18").Value = ""
    range("H19").Value = ""
    range("H20").Value = ""

    range("A1").Select

    MsgBox "Please enter the correct values for SHIFT #, SHIFT LENGTH, PART #, AND OPORATOR #, Thanks! Have a great day!!"

End If

Sheets("Front End").Protect ("29745")
Call timerchoose
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

> This copies the data from the front page to a raw data sheet every
>   hour:

```
Sub transfer()

Sheets("Front End").Unprotect ("29745")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim x As Long
    Dim v As Variant, r As range, rWhere As range

'set starting point at row 8
    x = 8
'defines the sheet the data is being coppied from and pasted to
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet: Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Front End")
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")

If sourceSheet.range("I3").Value = "" Then

    Call StartTimer
    Exit Sub


Else

    Do While range("L" & x).Value <> ""
'Checks if the unique code is in the raw data sheet or not
        v = sourceSheet.range("M" & x).Value
        Set rWhere = destSheet.range("S:S")
        Set r = rWhere.Find(what:=v, After:=rWhere(1))
        If r Is Nothing Then

'selects the next row where the 1st column is empty
            lMaxRows = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'pastes the data from the specified cells into the next empty row
            destSheet.range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("C2").Value
            destSheet.range("M" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("E2").Value
            destSheet.range("N" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("E4").Value
            destSheet.range("P" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("G4").Value
            destSheet.range("Q" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("C4").Value
            destSheet.range("O" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("I3").Value
            destSheet.range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("J" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("C" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("K" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("D" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("L" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("E" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("I" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("S" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("M" & x).Value

            x = x + 1
        Else
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Loop

    x = 8

    Do While range("D" & x).Value <> 0
    If range("E" & x).Value <> "" Then
'Checks if the unique code is in the raw data sheet or not
        v = sourceSheet.range("A" & x).Value
        Set rWhere = destSheet.range("S:S")
        Set r = rWhere.Find(what:=v, After:=rWhere(1))
        If r Is Nothing Then

'selects the next row where the 1st column is empty
            lMaxRows = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'pastes the data from the specified cells into the next empty row
            destSheet.range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("C2").Value
            destSheet.range("M" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("E2").Value
            destSheet.range("N" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("E4").Value
            destSheet.range("P" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("G4").Value
            destSheet.range("Q" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("C4").Value
            destSheet.range("O" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("I3").Value
            destSheet.range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("B" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("L" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("C" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("F" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("D" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("G" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("E" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("I" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("G" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("K" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("H" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("H" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("N" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("J" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("O" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("S" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("A" & x).Value

            x = x + 1
        Else
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Else
        x = x + 1
    End If
    Loop
'sorts Raw Data table after new data is added
    Dim ws  As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
'specifies how to sort the data
    With ws.Sort.SortFields
        .Clear
        .add Key:=ws.range("A2:A" & lMaxRows + 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .add Key:=ws.range("B2:B" & lMaxRows + 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'specifies range over which to sort
    End With
    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange ws.range("A1:S" & lMaxRows + 1)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With



End If


Sheets("Front End").Protect ("29745")


    Call SortDTWeek
    Call SortDTMonth
    Call StartTimer


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

> This checks a few cells constantly to see if they have been double
>   clicked, if so it puts the current time in that cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As range, cancel As Boolean)
'Adds downtime start and finish values
'Check to see if the click/selected cell is in columns I or J
    If Not Intersect(Target, range("J:K")) Is Nothing Then

'Make sure cell is in range
        If Target.Row > 7 And Target.Row <= 27 Then

'Update the value
            Target.Value = Time()
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

> Checks to see if a set of cells has been changed, if so it puts the
>   now() value in a corresponding "key" column

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
Sheets("Front End").Unprotect ("29745")
Dim cell As range

'Adds unique keyA values
'Check to see if the changed cell is in column E
    If Not Intersect(Target, range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If cell.Value <> vbNullString And Target.Row > 7 And Target.Row <= 20 Then
            'Update the "KeyA" value
                Sheets("Front End").range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Now()
            End If
        Next cell
    Else

'Adds unique keyB values
'Check to see if the changed cell is in column K
    If Not Intersect(Target, range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If cell.Value <> vbNullString And (Target.Row > "6" And Target.Row <= "27") Then
            'Update the "KeyM" value
                range("M" & Target.Row).Value = Now()
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End If
Sheets("Front End").Unprotect ("29745")
End Sub
```

thanks for any input this issue has been driving me crazy

Comment: Can you open the corrupted manually? If so, what if you handle/ignore the 1004 error in VBA like On Error Resume Next?

Comment: @MLind yes, the files are all fully function when opened manually. however, the error wont let me click continue, only end or debug.

Comment: To transfer data you seem to reuse the same file over and over again (like "Clears the page of data to prepare it for a new shift of entering data:"). Could one suspect this to put the file of small but re-occuring risks of getting corrupted. Can you use a brand new file for the data-transfer (just re-using the file-name)?

Comment: Did you try "On Error Resume Next" to turn Error handling off just prior to the Open command and then "On Error Goto 0" to turn it back on just after the Open command?

Comment: @MLind i have updated the question to show the code from the summary file that is trying to open each of the files and pull key info. also i can not create a new file each time because these workbooks are left up on pieces of manufacturing equipment 24/7 to track the efficiency and should not be closed

Comment: @MLind would using that piece of code not skip that part of the sub?

Comment: On Error Resume Next tells the execution to continue starting the next statement after the error.

Comment: @MLind i just tried putting that in my code and it just closed the workbook when it hit the error

Comment: what about Worbooks.Open...CorruptLoad = xlExtractData or ... CorruptLoad = xlRepairFile as descriped in the manual https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

Comment: @MLind i read that section but i dont understand how i would put it in my code line that i use the workbooks.open statement. would i leave everything as is but add CorruptLoad xlNormalLoad before filename:= ?

Comment: Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyWB, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, CorruptLoad := xlRepairFile or the same but with xlExtractData at the end

Comment: There are free addin available online that will clean the file for you. Such as: [The Excel VBA Code Cleaner](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm).

Comment: @MLind that worked! put it as an answer and ill mark it correct!

Comment: Thanks alot! I'm not that proud though, I just threw several suggestions on it until one happened to stick :)

Comment: @MLind thanks, i just posted the answer myself and gave you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @MLind suggested in the comments, to bypass the corrupted file error and pull some data out i added this to my code:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyWB, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, 
    CorruptLoad:=xlExtractData
```

and used

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

within the loop to prevent any pop up boxes from stopping the sub